# Bind local JavaScript variable to Polymer element outside of Polymer

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have a hierarchy in which a parent element supplies child elements with fairly complex objects.  However, when I want to create a demo page, a unit test, or supply variables from PHP I have to either shove everything into strings or have the child element fetch them from a global in a lifecycle callback.

The [auto-binding template](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-bind) allows one to share state *between* multiple Polymer elements. You can also setup a `dom-change` listener, but I can't seem to declare a variable before the child object has been stamped out.

Is there any way to supply a local or global variable to an element using the standard `<element property="{{variable}}">` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Get a handle to the auto-binding template and add a property to it, then you can bind to that property.

```
<template id="main" is="auto-binding">
   <my-element foo="{{bar}}"></my-element>
</template>

<script>
  var t = document.getElementById('main');
  t.bar = 'test';
</script>
```